# Problems with Vista loading a temporary user profile

Tags: windows-vista, user-profiles

I'm having a problem in Vista. My machine has four users, one for each of us in the house. Whenever a user logs in before me, they log out, and then I log in, Vista loads a temporary profile for me.

However, if I restart and log in, I get into my profile no problem. Two errors are written to the event log (see below), and I've searched everywhere for solutions.

1: Windows was unable to load the registry. The problem is often caused by insuff. memory or insuff. security rights. DETAIL - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. for C:\users\joe\ntuser.dat

I've got plenty of disk space and memory.

2:Windows cannot load the locally stored profile. Possible causes of this error include isufficient security rights or a corrupt local profile. DETAIL - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Thanks!

Comment: No updates for awhile--any solutions? I'm having the same problem in Win7 HomePrem 32bit. My events: http://pastebin.com/kULVt4qh

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating your self a new profile? or changing the security settings on your own account? Thats where I would start. Maybe a little more info could help us as to what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. If you use ZoneAlarm Personal firewall, it sometimes locks certain files within the default user profile. If that's the case, use another firewall. You may disable your firewall (whatever it is) to check if that's the problem.
2. This is somewhat unlikely:
   In case your ntuser.dat file is corrupted, delete it via another administrator logon. Reboot and Windows will recreate a new ntuser.dat. 
   (Create a system restore point first.)